# Get a difference between random seconds and now-then in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got a little bit of javascript that generates a random number that will count as milliseconds(Between 0 and 10 seconds).

Along with it i'm using the `getTime()` method to set a starttimer and a while later again to set a stoptimer.

With that i want to get the difference in milliseconds between the timedifference(`stoptimer-starttimer`) and the milliseconds i choose at random.

Something like: The random milliseconds is 1.3s and the timedifference is 1. The user is off by 0.3s.

```
millisecondsToPress = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)*1000; 
startTime = attempt.getCurrentTime();
```

And a little later a showresult is called which stops the time and should do the math

```
stopTime = attempt.getCurrentTime();
showResult();
```

And here's the getTime function:

```
var d = new Date();
return d.getTime();
```

And the showresult as it is now(Which is wrong :-p)
var secondsPressed = this.stopTime - this.startTime;

```
if (secondsPressed >= this.millisecondsToPress) {
    //The timedifference is bigger than the toPress. The player overshot!
    result = secondsPressed - this.millisecondsToPress;
} else {
    //The player undershot
    result = this.millisecondsToPress - secondsPressed;
}
```

I'm propably wrong with the milliseconds or something(*1000 or *100 etc)

Comment: Is `tartTime` just a typo in the question?

Comment: `Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)*1000;` will generate a random number between 1000 and 101000... for between 0 and 10000 use `Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);`

Comment: @ic3b3rg The upper bound is actually 100, not 101 - `Math.floor(0.9999*100) == 99`

Comment: @Alnitak That's true! I always thought 1 was the upper bound... now I know Math.random() `Returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your random time generator is giving you values between 1 and 100 seconds, and only in whole seconds because the `* 1000` happens after the random time has been rounded.  You probably want:

```
var millisecondsToPress = Math.floor(10000 * Math.random());
```

If you only care about the *magnitude* of the error, use `Math.abs()`

```
result = Math.abs(secondsPressed - this.millisecondsToPress) / 1000.0
```

with the division there to convert back to seconds.

To get the *numeric value* of the current time in milliseconds, you can just use `+new Date()` 
on older browsers, or `Date.now()` on newer browsers (the latter is more efficient because it doesn't instantiate an object).

Comment: The Math.abs() method is pretty handy. Thanks for that!

Comment: I wanted `Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)*100` by the way(1.3s not 1.301s) Your answer did the trick nonetheless! Thanks!

Comment: What granularity do you actually want - 100ms?  The code here will have 1ms granularity with range 0 - 9.999ms and it's not clear what your `+ 1` is there for.

Comment: Yeah it works without the +1 too. I really just want a number between 0.0 and 9.9 really. And that's what it seems to do now after a lot of refreshes :D